# Physical Intuition of Inelastic Mean Free Path

Tags: classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, scattering

The [inelastic mean free path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inelastic_mean_free_path) (IMFP) is a quasi-universal curve which describes how far a beam of electrons will travel through a material before scattering inelastically. I have been searching for derivations of a functional form but have not been successful; however, this is not my main question.

I am curious: is there an intuitive explanation as to why at low energy the mean free path is inversely proportional to the electron energy and why it is linear at high energy? I imagine it is because different scattering processes dominate in the two regimes, but I would like a definitive answer. Is there a way to intuitively picture the minimum (e.g. the minimum occurs when scattering from process x balances with that of process y)?

Comment: https://indico.cern.ch/event/145296/contributions/1381063/attachments/136866/194145/Particle-Interaction-Matter-upload.pdf may have more than you want to know...

Comment: I appreciate the link, it was quite informative. That being said, I couldn't find the answer I was looking for in those slides.